# State variable that keeps track of list of published items

Tags: swiftui

I am learning SwiftUI and having trouble with data flow. 
I can't figure out how to create a "state"-variable to keep track of a list of published child items.

**I need a variable that is true if at least one child item is selected.** These items are mapped to SwiftUI toggle-switches, which works. (Making a computed property is not allowed)

*Property wrapper cannot be applied to a computed property*

```
class Main : ObservableObject {
    @Published var items : [Item]

    //This is what i want, but not allowed
    @Published var selectedItemsExist : Bool {
        get {
            var exists = false
            for item in items {
                if item.selected {
                    exists = true
                    break
                }
            }
            return exists
        }
    }

    init(items: [Item]) {
        self.items = items
    }
}

class Item : Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    var id = UUID()
    var name : String!
    @Published var selected : Bool = false
}
```

And then in my view be able to do something like

```
if main.selectedItemsExist {
    Text("This text is shown if at least on toggle is on")
}
```

Any guidance appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below the demo of approach how this could be done. Tested as worked with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2

```
class Main : ObservableObject {

    @Published var items : [Item] {
        didSet { // << as item is value array will be updated on item changed
            var exists = false
            for item in items {
                if item.selected {
                    exists = true
                    break
                }
            }
            self.selectedItemsExist = exists
        }
    }

    @Published var selectedItemsExist : Bool = false

    init(items: [Item]) {
        self.items = items
    }
}


struct Item : Identifiable { // << value type, so changed on any property change
    var id = UUID()
    var name : String!
    var selected : Bool = false
    init(_ name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

struct TestCalculablePublishing: View {
    @ObservedObject var main = Main(items: [Item("1"), Item("2"), Item("3")])

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Test") {
                self.main.items[1].selected.toggle() // << just for test purpose
            }
            if main.selectedItemsExist {
                Text("This text is shown if at least on toggle is on")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestCalculablePublishing_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestCalculablePublishing()
    }
}
```